# Create POJOs from XML

Tags: xml, pojo

Is it possible to create POJOs directly just from XML, without XML schema?
I have very large XML file and it's almost impossible to write Java classes by hand.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), [jibx](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/). I had thought of using them in the past, but not really used them in a real app.

Comment: I've tried xstream, but I have a situation, where I have only XML file and no schema, no java class and I want a library to create Java classes according to XML file.